# Jenkins CI LDAP setup: very slow Log in

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I have the following setup:

- Apache Tomcat 7.0.32
- Jenkins CI 1.511

I need to Secure Jenkins so I have chosen the LDAP authentication plug in (version 1.2)

The set up of the LDAP seems to be ok since I can connect to the LDAP server.

The only issue I have is that it takes up to 1 minute to login.

This seems to be strange since we use LDAP for many others applications and the log in, in those application, takes 1 or 2 seconds.

Is there anyone that have experienced a similar issue and knows how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your backend LDAP service? Perhaps Jenkins is doing a stupid query, to a non-indexed attribute?  Can you log LDAP queries?  If so, it might be instructive to see them.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I can monitor the Network traffic with wireshark tool. I can save teh log in wireshark format. Wireshark is a open source tool. CAn yoou maybe read teh log if I post it? I can eventually do a screenshot of the Jenkins LDAP setup if that can help. Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I am new to this forum. How can attach a file to the post?

Comment: You could upload to susepaste.org or pastebin.org and then add a link here.

Comment: Hi i used the Susepart.org. I have two images: the first is the Jenkins CI setup [link](http://susepaste.org/9668bca5) . the second one is the Wireshark capture when I am logging in [link](http://susepaste.org/9f37facc). At eh moment I can log in in circa 20-25 seconds. I have changed the User filter option for narrowing down the search. Still this log in time is too much. Maybe looking at the following files you can get some info and help me.

Comment: Hi again. Solution on this issue is to change the groupSearchFilter in the  WEB-INF/security/LDAPBindSecurityRealm.groovy file in Jenkins as described in the LDAP plugin under Configuration [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin). Thank you so much for your help.